# Possible ways to reuse repeated logic and getOrElse chaining in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a logic like

```
if(condition) statement1 else if(condition) statement2 else .......
```

Code:

```
val a: Option[String] = if (source == "abc") Some(source) else None
val b: Option[String] = if (source == "cdf") Some(source) else None
......nor 3 4 statments as above

val test: String = a.getOrElse(b.getOrElse(StringUtils.EMPTY))
```

Question:

1. Can anyone suggest a better way to reuse the code with if logic in a functional way?
2. Any alternative to getOrElse chaining?

**Update**

By "reuse" I mean in case I have seven or eight if conditions. Any way to generalise the condition inside if and then reuse it? I want to create a filter.
I am new to Scala and am not sure if we can use high order functions or any other  approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your example, what it is exactly you are trying to do.
The functional way to write `if` is `.filter`, and you can use `.orElse` instead of `.getOrElse` ... But I don't quite understand the purpose of having those multiple assignments, and convertions of strings to options and back the way you wrote it. Most probably, they are unnecessary, and there is a better way to do what you want, but it's hard to suggest one without understanding of what it is that you actually need.

```
val a = Option(source).filter(_ == "abc")
val b = Option(source).filter(_ == "cdf") 

val test = a orElse b getOrElse("")
```

Alternatively, you could just write:

```
val test = Option(source).filter(Set("abc", "cdf")).getOrElse("")
```

Or even:

```
val test = source match {
  case "abc"|"cdf" => source
  case _ => ""
}
```

Comment: Updated the question  hope it clarifies now

Answer (score 0):

```
val test = source match
{
  case "abc" => /* your code here */
  case "cdf" => /* your code here */
  ...
  case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar with orElse, for me it is clearer way to manipulate Options:

```
a.orElse(b).getOrElse(StringUtils.EMPTY)
```